# Hyprland mouse icon disappears after Application start

Tags: linux, icons, mouse, nvidia, arch

My Mouse Cursor disappears after I launch any application. Everything else works as intended. Clicking, Draging, Mouse wheel. But I can|t see where the mouse is.

I tried to google for similar problems but did not find anything like that.

Details about the OS:
`

```
OS: ArcoLinux
Kernel: 6.1.28-1-lts
DE: Hyprland
Theme/Icons: Adwaita \[GTK2\], Adwaita-dark \[GTK3\]
Font: Canterell 11 \[GTK2/3\]
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 2700 (16) @3.200GHz
GPU Driver: NVIDIA 530.41.03
```

`

If anyone has an Idea why this happen or help me to get rid of this problem I am thankful for that.

Note: If information is missing, I provied more.

`hyprctl setcursor Adwaita-dark 24` doesn't work.
`hyprctl cursorpos` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$WLR_NO_HARDWARE_CURSORS` environment variable needs to be set to `1`, if `echo $WLR_NO_HARDWARE_CURSORS` doesn't return anything then that could be the issue.

In `~/.config/hypr/hyprland.conf` I've added the line: `env = WLR_NO_HARDWARE_CURSORS,1`.

This fixed the issue for me, hopefully it solves it for others.